# Parsing log files

Tags: regex, powershell, select, filter, paragraph

I'm trying to write a script to simplify the process of searching through a particular applications log files for specific information. So I thought maybe there's a way to convert them into an XML tree, and I'm off to a decent start....but The problem is, the application log files are an absolute mess if you ask me

Some entries are simple

```
2014/04/09 11:27:03 INFO  Some.code.function - Doing stuff
```

Ideally I'd like to turn the above into something like this

```
    <Message>
    <Date>2014/04/09</Date>
    <Time>11:48:38</Time>
    <Type>INFO</Type>
    <Source>Some.code.function</Source>
    <Sub>Doing stuff</Sub>
    </Message>
```

Other entries are something like this where there's additional information and line breaks

```
2014/04/09 11:27:04 INFO  Some.code.function - Something happens

changes: 
this stuff happened
```

I'd like to turn this last chunk into something like the above, but add the additional info into a section

```
    <Message>
    <Date>2014/04/09</Date>
    <Time>11:48:38</Time>
    <Type>INFO</Type>
    <Source>Some.code.function</Source>
    <Sub>Doing stuff</Sub>
    <details>changes: 
this stuff happened</details>
    </Message>
```

and then other messages, errors will be in the form of

```
2014/04/09 11:27:03 ERROR  Some.code.function - Something didn't work right
Log Entry: LONGARSEDGUID
Error Code: E3145
Application: Name
Details:
message information etc etc and more line breaks, this part of the message may add up to an unknown number of lines before the next entry
```

This last chunk I'd like to convert as the last to above examples, but adding XML nodes for log entry, error code, application, and again, details like so

```
    <Message>
    <Date>2014/04/09</Date>
    <Time>11:48:38</Time>
    <Type>ERROR  </Type>
    <Source>Some.code.function</Source>
    <Sub>Something didn't work right</Sub>
    <Entry>LONGARSEDGUID</Entry>
    <Code>E3145</Code>
    <Application>Name</Application>
    <details>message information etc etc and more line breaks, this part of the message may add up to an unknown number of lines before the next entry</details>
    </Message>
```

Now I know that Select-String has a context option which would let me select a number of lines after the line I've filtered, the problem is, this isn't a constant number.

I'm thinking a regular expression would also me to select the paragraph chunk before the date string, but regular expressions are not a strong point of mine, and I thought there might be a better way because the one constant is that new entries start with a date string

the idea though is to either break these up into xml or tables of sorts and then from there I'm hoping it might take the last or filtering non relevant or recurring messages a little easier

I have a sample I just tossed on pastebin after removing/replacing a few bits of information for privacy reasons

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=M9iShyT2

Comment: How big are these files?  It simpler if the files are small enough that the entire file can be read into memory, but you may run into memory issues if they get to be over a few hundred meg, depending on your available resources.

Comment: the max log size by default is 5mb, and it will rollover at that size and retain 5 previous logs (in separate files), so 30mb at most if i wanted to pass them all through at once. Some of the detail entries might contain entire SQL queries or anywhere from 5-50 (give or take) lines of additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is kind of late, I got tied up with work for a bit there (darn work expecting me to be productive while on their dime). I ended up with something similar to Ansgar Wiechers solution, but formatted things into objects and collected those into an array. It doesn't manage your XML that you added later, but this gives you a nice array of objects to work with for the other records. I'll explain the main RegEx line here, I'll comment in-line where it's practical.

'(^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) [\d+?] (\w+?) {1,2}(.+?) - (.+)$' is the Regex that detects the start of a new record. I started to explain it, but there are probably better resources for you to learn RegEx than me explaining it to me. See [this RegEx101.com link](http://regex101.com/r/mU8mJ7) for a full breakdown and examples.

```
$Records=@() #Create empty array that we will populate with custom objects later
$Event = $Null #make sure nothing in $Event to give script a clean start
Get-Content 'C:\temp\test1.txt' | #Load file, and start looping through it line-by-line.
?{![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)}|% { #Filter out blank lines, and then perform the following on each line
  if ($_ -match '(^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \[\d+?] (\w+?) {1,2}(.+?) - (.+)$') { #New Record Detector line! If it finds this RegEx match, it means we're starting a new record.
    if ($Event) { #If there's already a record in progress, add it to the Array
      $Records+=$Event
    }
    $Event = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ #Create a custom PSObject object with these properties that we just got from that RegEx match
DateStamp = [datetime](get-date $Matches[1]) #We convert the date/time stamp into an actual DateTime object. That way sorting works better, and you can compare it to real dates if needed.
Type = $Matches[2]
Source = $Matches[3]
Message = $Matches[4]}
```

Ok, little pause for the cause here. `$Matches` isn't defined by me, why am I referencing it? . When PowerShell gets matches from a RegEx expression it automagically stores the resulting matches in $Matches. So all the groups that we just matched in parenthesis become $Matches[1], $Matches[2], and so on. Yes, it's an array, and there is a $Matches[0], but that is the entire string that was matched against, not just the groups that matched. We now return you to your regularly scheduled script...

```
  } else { #End of the 'New Record' section. If it's not a new record if does the following
    if($_ -match "^((?:[^ ^\[])(?:\w| |\.)+?):(.*)$"){
```

RegEx match again. It starts off by stating that this has to be the beginning of the string with the carat character (^). Then it says (in a non-capturing group noted by the `(?:<stuff>)` format, which really for my purposes just means it won't show up in $Matches) `[^ \[]`; that means that the next character can not be a space or opening bracket (escaped with a ), just to speed things up and skip those lines for this check. If you have things in brackets `[]` and the first character is a carat it means 'don't match anything in these brackets'.

I actually just changed this next part to include periods, and used \w instead of [a-zA-Z0-9] because it's essentially the same thing but shorter. \w is a "word character" in RegEx, and includes letters, numbers, and the underscore. I'm not sure why the underscore is considered part of a word, but I don't make the rules I just play the game. I was using [a-zA-Z0-9] which matches anything between 'a' and 'z' (lowercase), anything between 'A' and 'Z' (uppercase), and anything between '0' and '9'. At the risk of including the underscore character \w is a lot shorter and simpler.

Then the actual capturing part of this RegEx. This has 2 groups, the first is letters, numbers, underscores, spaces, and periods (escaped with a \ because '.' on it's own matches any character). Then a colon. Then a second group that is everything else until the end of the line.

```
        $Field = $Matches[1] #Everything before the colon is the name of the field
        $Value = $Matches[2].trim() #everything after the colon is the data in that field
        $Event | Add-Member $Field $Value #Add the Field to $Event as a NoteProperty, with a value of $Value. Those two are actually positional parameters for Add-Member, so we don't have to go and specify what kind of member, specify what the name is, and what the value is. Just Add-Member <[string]name> <value can be a string, array, yeti, whatever... it's not picky>
        } #End of New Field for current record
    else{$Value = $_} #If it didn't find the regex to determine if it is a new field then this is just more data from the last field, so don't change the field, just set it all as data.

    } else { #If it didn't find the regex then this is just more data from the last field, so don't change the field, just set it all as data.the field does not 'not exist') do this:
            $Event.$Field += if(![string]::isNullOrEmpty($Event.$Field)){"`r`n$_"}else{$_}}
```

This is a long explanation for a fairly short bit of code. Really all it does is add data to the field! This has an inverted (prefixed with `!`) `If` check to see if the current field has any data, if it, or if it is currently Null or Empty. If it is empty it adds a new line, and then adds the $Value data. If it doesn't have any data it skips the new line bit, and just adds the data.

```
    }
  }
}
$Records+=$Event #Adds the last event to the array of records.
```

Sorry, I'm not very good with XML. But at least this gets you clean records.

**Edit:** Ok, code is notated now, hopefully everything is explained well enough. If something is still confusing perhaps I can refer you to a site that explains better than I can. I ran the above against your sample input in PasteBin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I won't lie, I'm having a hard time reading it. It's a little beyond my abilities and I couldn't get it to give me anything with my sample log file unfortunately. I do however appreciate the effort.

Comment: I threw some on pastebin if it helps. It may have helped if my earlier examples were a little more accurate. There's a [2134] in the entry lines that I completely overlooked and have no desire to work with. I edited my original topic with a small pastebin sample, you'll probably quickly understand why I'm trying to make them a little more human readable. Comments in your sample code would be great though if you don't mind helping out. I really do appreciate the effort so far.

Comment: That does work great, and 50 lines shorter LOL. Except one little thing. with an = sign

it turned this

 2014/04/09 12:21:04 [201] INFO  ActionManagers.ActionNwkScan - Scanning completely done - time taken: 23 secs.
 2014/04/09 12:21:04 [201] ERROR Device - Error updating DeviceID = 29
 DataAccess.SqlSqlHelperException: [Sql=...

into this

 DateStamp : 2014/04/09 12:21:04
 Message   : Scanning completely done - time taken: 23 secs.
 Source    : ActionManagers.ActionNwkScan
 Type      : INFO
 Details   : 2014/04/09 12:21:04 [201] ERROR Device - Error updating DeviceID = 29DataAccess.Sql...

Comment: sigh, that didn't work. I put it on paste bin to show

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WCS9y3fv

Comment: Updated answer with a little optimization, a fix (added `.` to possible field names), and lots of explaining.

Comment: wow, that does the trick indeed. I've tweaked it into a module that I can use now. It will definitely make my job a little easier now when I have to sort through those on an an almost daily basis. Thanks a lot, you've no idea

Comment: If this answer provided a solution to your original questions please mark it as the accepted answer. Not only does it help future users looking for help with similar questions, it gives my reputation on the site a small boost =)

Comment: ah, yes, hadn't checked it yet. still reading some of the comments and notation and toying chunks in the ISE to help my understanding, but yes, it absolutely answers my question and I believe I just marked it answered.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to deal with such files is to process them line by line. Each log entry starts with a timestamp and ends when the next line starting with a timestamp appears, so you could do something like this:

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.log' | % {
  if ($_ -match '^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}') {
    if ($logRecord) {
      # If a current log record exists, it is complete now, so it can be added
      # to your XML or whatever, e.g.:

      $logRecord -match '^(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (\S+) ...'

      $message = $xml.CreateElement('Message')

      $date = $xml.CreateElement('Date')
      $date.InnerText = $matches[1]
      $message.AppendChild($date)

      $time = $xml.CreateElement('Time')
      $time.InnerText = $matches[2]
      $message.AppendChild($time)

      $type = $xml.CreateElement('Type')
      $type.InnerText = $matches[3]
      $message.AppendChild($type)

      ...

      $xml.SelectSingleNode('...').AppendChild($message)
    }
    $logRecord = $_          # start new record
  } else {
    $logRecord += "`r`n$_"   # append to current record
  }
}
```

Comment: I did find something along those lines, and I'm looking for something a little more than that. I should have been clearer in my first post which i just revised

Comment: actually, I'm toying with that and I see what's happening, I think I may be able to adapt that to what I have going.

Comment: @Serge111 You can process each log record according to your needs in the nested conditional. I added some sample code.

Comment: It took me some time to figure it out. It helped me to reformat the brackets though so I could read it properly but I managed to get this working. I ended up having it pipe the log entries to the function that I had started with initially. I'm still adding finishing touches, but this did the trick for separating the log entries into something I'm able to work with. My solution may not be as elegant, but it works for me